# How to insert records from flat file in to sql database table?

Tags: java, sql

I am currently tyring to copy data from a flat file into SQL tables and record this transaction in a log table
flat file colums

```
table name=personal data

firstname,
lastname,
age,
date_of_birth,
state,
country
```

and the sql table name=inbox

```
colums=
firstname varchar,
lastname varchar,
age int,
date_of_birth date,
state varchar,
country varchar,
```

data in flat file are separated by comas. I want the table to be sensitive to data types like firstname colum should not hold int data type and so on. And if the data type are wrong it should send the flatfile to another table called
outbox

I also want it to have a log table called audit_rec that keep track of all copies done and failed 
colums=

```
timecopied timespam()
name_of_file
failed_to_copy
reason_of_failure
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no standard SQL way to import a flat file, but many SQL implementations include an extension to provide such a capability. For example MySQL has the "load data" statement and Postgres has "copy from". You should check the documentation for whatever DB you're using and see what's available and what the syntax is.

That said, your statement that when the data are not the correct type you want to write the record to another file probably puts you outside of what any built-in language feature is going to do for you. You're probably going to have to write a program that reads the records one by one, parses each, checks for errors, and then does an insert statement to the appropriate file.